# can't use more than one javascript function for one id

Tags: javascript

I use 2 function input file foto for valid extension and replace label with foto's name

html code:

```
<input class="foto" type='file' name='propic' id="aa" class="required" value="<?php echo "$FOTO"; ?>" onchange="pressed()"><label style="font-weight:normal; width:80px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;" id="fileLabel"><?php echo "$FOTO"; ?></label>
```

javascript code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    window.pressed = function(){

if(a.value ==  "")
    {
        fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose file";
    }
    else
    {
        var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
    }
};

a.onchange = function(e){ 
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)[1];
    switch(ext)
    {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
            break;
        default:
            alert('File is not valid!');
            this.value='';
    }
};
</script>
```

Only one function working, that is function for valid file extension.. How to make other function work ??

Comment: window.pressed? when/how do you expect to trigger this event? And where `fileLabel` variable is defined? Have you any error in the js console?

Comment: `<input [...] onchange="pressed()">`

Comment: @J.Beyer I have input it..

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan window.pressed when input file pressed to open window browser.. filelabel defined in label tag and i don't have any error in the js console

Comment: sry, that was @FabrizioCalderan .. and you need to define filelabel in the js-code, too. The reason you aren't getting an error is that window.pressed is not invoked, because you overwrite a.onchange. Have a look at `addEventListener()`.

Comment: sorry @J.Beyer, i have tried to define it but still the same result.. now i am blank, i don't have much time. please help me.. how to define it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    var fileLabel = document.getElementById('fileLabel');
    updateLabel = function(){
        if(a.value ==  "")
        {
            fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose file";
        }
        else
        {
            var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
            fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
        }
    };

    validateExtension = function(e){ 
        var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)[1];
        switch(ext)
        {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'png':
                break;
            default:
                alert('File is not valid!');
                this.value='';
        }
    };
    a.addEventListener('change',validateExtension,false);
    a.addEventListener('change',updateLabel,false);
</script>
```

and remove the `onchange` from the html-code.

Comment: Thank you so much, both are working now.. i will give you a medal :D

Comment: No problem :) But take note that some IE-versions don't know addEventListener - I'd recommend using jQuery's `bind()`.